# Magento equivalent of ALTER IGNORE TABLE?

Tags: database, mysql

I am writing a setup script that adds a unique index to an existing table, but I don't bother iterating through the whole dataset.

Is there a way to specify an `IGNORE` keyword when I call `addIndex()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13885/magento-insert-ignore-into) and [answer it links to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql) would be helpful or provide you some workaround, because `Zend_Db` doesn't support `IGNORE`.

Comment: If they are not supported, this could be the closest answer I can get. Accepting this, and thanks.